# Javascript - Going from one switch statement case to a different switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, swap

I'm trying to have a case in a switch statement that jumps into a different switch statement.

In practice, I want the user to type "close page" in a text box and, before the browser closes the page, I want the user to be asked if he is sure about it. Typing "yes" will close the page, and typing "no" will go back to the previous switch statement.

I need to use a switch statement because there are many other things the user can type into the textbox, which generate different feedback.

I used a different textbox for each switch statement, swapping them when necessary, to try to be able to call both functions with the same key.

This is what I have. But it does not work...
Any help?

```js
        function SwapDivs(div1, div2) {
            d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
            d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
            if (d2.style.display == "none") {
                d1.style.display = "none";
                d2.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                d1.style.display = "block";
                d2.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function myFunction01() {
            var text;
            var answers = document.getElementById("myInput01"").value;
            switch (answers) {
                case "close page":
                    text = "are you sure?";
                    SwapDivs('div01', 'div02');
                    break;
                default:
                    text = "no valid input";
            }
            document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
        }

        function myFunction02() {
            var text;
            var answers = document.getElementById("myInput02").value;
            switch (answers) {
                case "yes":
                    text = "Why?";
                    break;
                case "no":
                    text = "Good!";
                    break;
                default:
                    text = "no valid input";
            }
            document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
        }
```

```html
    <p id="feedback"></p>

    <div id="div01" style="display:block">
        <input id="myInput01" type="text" placeholder="This is TextBox 01." onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction01();">
    </div>

    <div id="div02" style="display:none">
        <input id="myInput02" type="text" placeholder="This is TextBox 02." onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction02();">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra quote on your first function:

`var answers = document.getElementById("myInput01"").value;`

It should be:

`var answers = document.getElementById("myInput01").value;`

I understand the behaviour is:

- If user enters any text other than "close page", we give them feedback of invalid input.

  - If user enters "close page", we ask them if they are sure and change to input 2.
  - On input 2, if they input yes we say why, if they input no we say good else say no valid input.

If this is expected, the code works for me.

You can run this one below (converted to ES6):

```js
const SwapDivs = (div1, div2) => {
  const d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  const d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  if (d2.style.display == "none") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    d2.style.display = "none";
  }
};

const myFunction01 = () => {
  let text;
  const answers = document.getElementById("myInput01").value;
  switch (answers) {
    case "close page":
      text = "are you sure?";
      SwapDivs('div01', 'div02');
      break;
    default:
      text = "no valid input";
  }
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
};

const myFunction02 = () => {
  let text;
  const answers = document.getElementById("myInput02").value;
  switch (answers) {
    case "yes":
      text = "Why?";
      break;
    case "no":
      text = "Good!";
      break;
    default:
      text = "no valid input";
  }
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
};
```

```html
<p id="feedback"></p>

    <div id="div01" style="display:block">
        <input id="myInput01" type="text" placeholder="This is TextBox 01." onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction01();">
    </div>

    <div id="div02" style="display:none">
        <input id="myInput02" type="text" placeholder="This is TextBox 02." onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction02();">
    </div>
```